# Is it possible to scroll a popup via keyboard?

Tags: key-bindings, scrolling, popup

If I do `:let id = popup_create(['hello', 'hello', ... a lot of these, 'hello'], {})`, I can reproduce the case of a popup that contains more items that its height, thus having a scrollbar.

How do I scroll that bar via keyboard? Is it possible?

`:help popup-scrollbar` mentions the mouse several times, so it suggests to me that probably it's simply not possible to scroll via keyboard. Is that the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging I found this [great blog post](https://fortime.ws/blog/2020/03/14/20200312-01/) by @fortime.

I adapted their code for my needs (fixed a bug and keep the scrollbar visible):

```
function! ScrollPopup(nlines)
    let winids = popup_list()
    if len(winids) == 0
        return
    endif

    " Ignore hidden popups
    let prop = popup_getpos(winids[0])
    if prop.visible != 1
        return
    endif

    let firstline = prop.firstline + a:nlines
    let buf_lastline = str2nr(trim(win_execute(winids[0], "echo line('$')")))
    if firstline < 1
        let firstline = 1
    elseif prop.lastline + a:nlines > buf_lastline
        let firstline = buf_lastline + prop.firstline - prop.lastline
    endif

    call popup_setoptions(winids[0], {'firstline': firstline})
endfunction
```

You can add your own keybindings to call `ScrollPopup`, for example:

```
nnoremap <C-j> :call ScrollPopup(3)<CR>
nnoremap <C-k> :call ScrollPopup(-3)<CR>
```

Comment: Nice answer & Welcome vi.SE deox

Comment: Awesome, can't thank you enough